# How to use a universal player iframe to display videos

Tags: javascript, iframe, video, knockout.js

I am not sure how to ask this question properly but i am having a feature of letting the user add an embed video code along with video title to display video on the page.

I am using the universal iframe from vimeo's site which is:

```
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/VIDEO_ID" width="WIDTH" height="HEIGHT" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I am using knockout to bind and display the data. 
So in my model i have

```
var videoModel = function(data){
   self={
       title: ko.observable(data.title || ''),
       embedCode: ko.observable(data.embedCode || '')
    };
   self.videoInfo = function(){..//open form for user to enter video title and embed code..}

}
```

In my view page i have the option for the user to click to open the video info entry but once the info is saved the iframe should be displayed with the video values. And this is where i am having trouble... This is what i currently have:

```
    <!-- ko if: edit -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: content().title -->
            <a target="_blank" data-bind="click: videoInfo">Add/Edit Video</a>
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko ifnot: edit -->
    <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/VIDEO_ID" width="WIDTH" height="HEIGHT" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

Here is a sample of an video embed code a user might save to display:

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/92936956" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
<p><a href="https://vimeo.com/92936956">The BIG Breakfast</a> from <a href="https://vimeo.com/vanderkloot">William VanDerKloot</a> on <a href="https://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>
```

I am not sure what i need to do or missing to ensure that the saved video is displayed in the iframe. Currently after i save i get `Oops!
The embed code for this video is not valid.` But when i debug in the console i see that the saved data is there. I believe that the actual video id that is saved is not being rendered in place of the `VIDEO_ID` in the `iframe`

Comment: need more code. how are you setting edit, video_id, width observable etc?

Comment: @Dandy for the edit i am having a popup displayed where the user enters a title and the embed code of the video they want and then save. I have that part working fine. It is getting the embed code to actually display in the iframe is the problem. I am not sure how to pass in the embed code values into the iframe as parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `html` binding to display the embed code if you have it stored in an observable. Something like

```
<textarea rows=10 cols=50 data-bind="textInput: embedCode" placeholder="Insert embed code"></textarea>
<hr />
<span data-bind="html: embedCode"></span>

function vm(){
    var self = this;
    self.embedCode = ko.observable();
}
ko.applyBindings(new vm())
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/newuserjs/7wxLxgd1/

Comment: Wow - i guess i was overthinking this. This worked great! Thanks! I didn't consider the `html` for binding